# ASPState database

Tags: asp.net, aspstate

I've a question that i can't seem to find the answer to anywhere, i have nine applications, eight of which run .NET 2.0 and have been running for 8 years. All of which uses an ASP state database. More recently I have a new site - running .NET 4.0.

(It must be said at this point none of the previous sites can be upgraded due to using Bluedragon which is incompatible with versions over 3.5).

I also have one database server that is running a state database created in the year 2007....

Can I simply point my .NET 4.0 web application to the existing StateDB without any expected hinderances? On doing the most rudimentary research the schemas are indeed the same it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually yes :) This has been running for almost a year now with no side affects at all.